# Spatial where clause in Ruby Sequeĺ

Tags: ruby, postgresql, postgis, sequel

How can I write this SQL query in Ruby Sequel:

```
SELECT
  polygon.geometry, count(line)
FROM
  polygon, line
WHERE
  st_intersects(line.geometry, polygon.geometry)
GROUP BY
  polygon.geometry
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way but this is my stab at a solution:

```
DB.from(:polygon, :line)
  .where('st_intersects(line.geometry, polygon.geometry')
  .select('polygon.geometry, count(line)')
  .group_by(:polygon__geometry)
```

Generated SQL Query (I did this with an Oracle DB but results should be the same) :

```
#<Sequel::Oracle::Dataset: "SELECT 'polygon.geometry, count(line)' FROM \"POLYGON\", \"LINE\" WHERE (st_intersects(line.geometry, polygon.geometry) GROUP BY \"POLYGON\".\"GEOMETRY\"">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB[:polygon, :line].
  select_group(:polygon__geometry).
  select_append{count(line)}.
  where{st_intersects(:line__geometry, :polygon__geometry)}
```